# What causes this NullPointerException in Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i'm currently working on a Android application which draw a navigation Path from current location to a specific place selected on a spinner. This is my first Android application it works great so far but when i click the button to draw the navigation line the application crashes with an NullPointerException and i have absolutely no idea why? Maybe someone here can figure this out.
I know what a NullPointerException is, but i cant understand where my issue in the code is. Searching 3 days now. Please can someone help me.

For testing purposes i decide to set preset LatLng's in getMapsApiDirectionsUrl().

This is the class which contains the error:

```
package com.example.dl.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by dl on 30.11.15.
*/
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MapShow extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final LatLng Sontheim = new LatLng(49.12194, 9.21092);
private static final LatLng Eurpaplatz = new LatLng(49.148396, 9.2164799);
private static final LatLng Kuenzelsau = new LatLng(49.2755224, 9.71216623);
private static final LatLng Schwaebisch_Hall = new LatLng(49.1125398, 9.7436008);

private GoogleMap mMap;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    if (id == R.id.action_settings2) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_settings3) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapshow);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    // mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(49.12194, 9.21092), 15.0f));
    // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(49.12194, 9.21092)).title("Hochschule Heilbronn - Campus Sontheim"));

    //Calculate Direction
    String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
    ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.dl.myapplication/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Maps Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.dl.myapplication/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {

    /*location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    LatLng destination;
    String spinner_value = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    // Get Destination
    if (spinner_value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.eu_name))){
        destination = EUROPAPLATZ;
    } else if (spinner_value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.ku_name))){
        destination = KUENZELSAU;
    } else if (spinner_value.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.sh_name))){
        destination = SCHWAEBISCH_HALL;
    } else {
        destination = SONTHEIM;
    }*/

    // Check if location is available nicht vergessen!!!
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    //urlString.append(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    urlString.append(Sontheim.latitude);
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Sontheim.longitude);
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString.append(Kuenzelsau.latitude);
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Kuenzelsau.latitude);
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");


    /*double midpoint_lat = (location.getLatitude() + destination.latitude) / 2;
    double midpoint_lng = (location.getLongitude() + destination.longitude) / 2;

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(midpoint_lat, midpoint_lng)));*/

    // dynamisches zoom level hinzufügen falls möglich
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9));

    return urlString.toString();
}


private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";
        try {
            HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
            data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }
}

private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        points = null;
        PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

        // traversing through routes
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
            polyLineOptions.width(5);
            polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }
}



}
```

and this is the error log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.dl.myapplication, PID: 2251
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'float com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions.c' on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aw.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.eu.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:137)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                   at com.example.dl.myapplication.MapShow$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapShow.java:272)
>                                                                                   at com.example.dl.myapplication.MapShow$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MapShow.java:225)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: There is a good chance the issue is that `polyLineOptions` is null in `mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);`

Comment: okay sorry i have searched but found nothing specific. Can you link the the answered post? 
And yes, the issue is in 
`mMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);`
but i down't know why.